# Should xsd schema file pass validation against itself?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have a Java app where I have to validate xml file provided by the user against the XSD schema. In my application I use SAX parser. I tested it with several test xml-files and was satisfied with the result. However, let's say for fun, instead of input xml file I put the validating xsd schema itself. Strangely, it passed the validation. I am wondering if this is the right behavior. Simply put, should xsd schema file pass validation against itself?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

Of course there are exceptions, that is, there are some XSD schemas for which a schema is a valid instance, for example those that have a wildcard allowing any content provided it is in a different namespace.